# Dexie - Query table and sort

Tags: angular, dexie

I have this method that works well:

```
  getOrders(params): Observable<any> 
  {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.WebDBService.tbOrder.orderBy('[username+annord+tipord+numord]').reverse().toArray());
  }
```

it returns all the table data properly sorted.

Now I want to filter the tbOrder by **username** property but I don't know how to combine query filters with orderBy method...

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply sorting above a query, use [sortBy()](http://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.sortBy()). It works like toArray() but sorts the resulting array using the given property.